# How to retrieve specific values in my form ? Symfony 6.0.2

Tags: forms, symfony

I try to define values in my search form, so that when user comes back to the form, he retrieves previous values he entered. I tried this, but it seems it's not the solution because I don't the results as expected.

How can I retrieve values previously entered in my search form ?

Thank you for your help.

**search.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Liste des sorties et des activités !{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
    <p>Où souhaites-tu faire une sortie ou une activité ?</p>
    {{ form_widget(form.bigcity, {'attr' : {'class' : 'mb-3'}, 'value' : app.session.get('bigcity.name')} ) }}
    <p>Quel type de sortie ou d’activité t’intéresse ?</p>
    {{ form_widget(form.category, {'attr' : {'class' : 'mb-3'}, 'value' : app.session.get('category.title')} ) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.save, {'label': 'Je valide', 'attr' : {'class' : 'btn'}} ) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

**SearchType.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\BigCity;
use App\Entity\Categories;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('bigcity', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => BigCity::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionne une grande ville',
            ])
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Categories::class,
                'choice_label' => 'image',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

**EventsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Form\SearchType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{   
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(Request $request, SessionInterface $sessionInterface)
    {   
        $data = $request->query->all();
        $sessionFormData  = $sessionInterface->get('data');

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $data);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $sessionInterface->set('data', $data);
            return $this->render('front/events.html.twig', $data);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('front/search.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form
        ]);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248280/discussion-on-question-by-emilie-tossan-how-to-retrieve-specific-values-in-my-fo).

Answer (score 1):

can you show the controller code?
Otherwise try to use the form in GET and then use the Request object to get the last value entered.
Exp:

```php
{{ app.request.query.get('bigcity.name') }}
```

**EDIT**
By default, a form will be submitted via an HTTP POST request to the same URL under which the form was rendered.
Change the method of your form
**in SearchType.php**

```php
//SearchType.php
...
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null,
            'method' => 'GET'
        ]);
    }
```

**Or in Controller**

```php
//EventsController.php
$form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $data, ['method' => 'GET']);
```

**Or in your template**

```php
//search.html.twig
{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'GET'}) }}
```

**EDIT 2**
After changing the submission method, change this

```php
//In template(search.html.twig)
...
app.session.get('bigcity.name')
...
```

to this

```php
...
app.session.get('data').bigcity.id
...
```

Need some help?:

- [Accessing Request Data](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data)
- [Search, the Request Object & OR Query Logic (SymfonyCasts)](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/search-form#symfonys-request-object)

Comment: Thank you jtech237. I just added my controller in my description;

Comment: I tried your solution. It didn't work.

Comment: @EmilieTossan Your form is submitted using what method? Try my method by submitting your form with the GET method. Unless you want to use the POST method?

Comment: I think I already use GET method.

Comment: I think it can't be otherwise because my form is a search form.

Comment: Tell me if I am thinking wrong. :)

Comment: In any case, you have all the information in my description...

Comment: By default, a form will be submitted via an HTTP POST request to the same URL under which the form was rendered. Inspect your rendered code in the browser.

Comment: I have modified my answer. Everything should work

Comment: Thank you jtech237. How do I set get method ?

Comment: I set GET method but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Also, I didn't write $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $data); because $data is an empty array.

Comment: Tested solution: Replaces `app.session.get('bigcity.name')` by `app.session.get('data').bigcity.id`

Comment: Ok jtech237. I just did. But $data is empty and when I use $sessionFormData for $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $sessionFormData); I have this error : Entity of type "App\Entity\BigCity" passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?

Comment: I think the problem is that I don't know what information I use when I create the form.

Comment: Hello jtech237. The error has been fixed (thanks to another ticket). I will be able to concentrate again on this question, until I find the solution...

Comment: So it looks like app.session.get('data').bigcity.id didn't lead to the expected result, but this might be the right path. I will continue to dig a little deeper into this.

Comment: Ok, it worked now. But only for bigcity. :)

Comment: Hi, I was busy. For the categories you can do the same thing `app.session.get('data').categories.id`

Comment: Hello jtech237. Thank you very much for your answer. I tried but surprisedly, the related category input isn't checked.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `Request` object in form entity

```
public function search(Request $request, SessionInterface $sessionInterface)
{   
    //$data = $request->query->all();
    $sessionFormData  = $sessionInterface->get('data');

    $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $request);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $sessionInterface->set('data', $data);
        return $this->render('front/events.html.twig', $data);
    }

    return $this->renderForm('front/search.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form
    ]);
}
```

And in twig file just mention fields

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <p>Où souhaites-tu faire une sortie ou une activité ?</p>
    {{ form_widget(form.bigcity, {'attr' : {'class' : 'mb-3'}} ) }}
    <p>Quel type de sortie ou d’activité t’intéresse ?</p>
    {{ form_widget(form.category, {'attr' : {'class' : 'mb-3'}} ) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.save, {'label': 'Je valide', 'attr' : {'class' : 'btn'}} ) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Please share more details. How would that load data from the session into the form in case the form is not submitted yet?