# With Symfony how do I retrieve the data provided in the search form ? Error : Variable does not exist

Tags: forms, symfony, variables, controller

I am trying to display a list of events that users has chosen according to two features : the big city and the category. So he needs to select 'bigcity' and 'category' with a search form before landing on events page.

First I succeeded to display selected informations in a  tag, but when I tried to display the list of events, I got this error `Variable "category" does not exist.` like my twig or my controller 'forgot' what bigcity and category are.

I don't understand what the problem can be.

**EventsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use App\Form\SearchType;
use App\Repository\EventsRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(
        Request $request, 
        SessionInterface $sessionInterface,
    ){   
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $sessionSearchFormData  = $sessionInterface->get('searchFormData');

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, ['data' => $sessionSearchFormData]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();
            $sessionInterface->set('searchFormData', $data);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('events', [$data]);
        }
        return $this->renderForm('front/search.html.twig', [ 
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/events', name: 'events')]
    public function events(
        EventsRepository $eventsRepository, 
    ){
        $events = $eventsRepository->findAll();
        return $this->render("front/events.html.twig", ['events' => $events]);
    }
}
```

**search.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Liste des sorties et des activités !{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

{{ form_start(form) }}

    <p>Où souhaites-tu faire une sortie ou une activité ?</p>
    {{ form_widget(form.bigcity) }}

    <p>Quel type de sortie ou d’activité t’intéresse ?</p>
    {{ form_widget(form.category) }}

    {{ form_widget(form.save, {'label': 'Je valide') }}

{{ form_end(form) }}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**events.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Liste des activités {{ category.title }} à {{ bigcity.name }}{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<div class="events">

    <h1 class="display-6 pt-3">
        <img src="{{ asset('img/logos/') }}{{ category.image }}" alt="{{ category.title }}" width="auto" height="40">
        à <b class="me-1">{{ bigcity.name }}</b>
    </h1>

    <div class="vr fixed-top start-50"></div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

            <h2 class="text-center my-4">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/titres/zpeak-sorties.svg') }}" alt="Les Zpeak Sorties !">
            </h2>

            <ul class="list-group">

            {% for event in events %}
                    
            {% if event and event.organizer.status == 'organizer' %}

                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/flag_images/' ~ event.spokenlanguage.image) }}" alt="Drapeau {{ event.spokenlanguage.name }}" class="me-2"> {{ event.title }}
                </a>

            {% else %}

                <p>Il n'y a pas de zpeak sortie organisée.</p>

            {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

            <h2 class="text-center my-4">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/titres/zpeak-idees.svg') }}" alt="Les Zpeak Idées !">
            </h2>

            <ul class="list-group">

            {% for event in events %}
            
            {% if event and event.organizer.status == 'member' %}
                    
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/flag_images/' ~ event.spokenlanguage.image) }}" alt="Drapeau {{ event.spokenlanguage.name }}" class="me-2"> {{ event.title }}
                </a>

            {% else %}

                <p>Il n'y a pas de zpeak idée proposée.</p>

            {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

            </ul>
            
        </div>
    
    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**SearchType.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\BigCity;
use App\Entity\Categories;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $bigcity = $options['sessionSearchFormData'] !== null ? $options['sessionSearchFormData']['bigcity'] : '';
        $category = $options['sessionSearchFormData'] !== null ? $options['sessionSearchFormData']['category'] : '';

        $builder
            ->add('bigcity', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => BigCity::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionne une grande ville',
                'data'=> $bigcity !== null ? $this->entityManager->getRepository(BigCity::class)->find($bigcity) : '',
            ])
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Categories::class,
                'choice_label' => 'image',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'data'=> $category !== null ? $this->entityManager->getRepository(Categories::class)->find($category) : '',
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null,
            'sessionSearchFormData' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean that the error is here ? {% block title %}Liste des activités {{ category.title }} à {{ bigcity.name }}{% endblock %}

Comment: hous yes, my error occurred there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the satisfying solution here :

**EventsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use App\Form\SearchType;
use App\Repository\BigCityRepository;
use App\Repository\EventsRepository;
use App\Repository\CategoriesRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(
        Request $request, 
        SessionInterface $sessionInterface,
        EventsRepository $eventsRepository,
    ){   
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $sessionSearchFormData  = $sessionInterface->get('searchFormData');

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, ['data' => $sessionSearchFormData]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();
            $sessionInterface->set('searchFormData', $data);
            
            $events = $eventsRepository->findAll();
            
            return $this->render("front/events.html.twig", [
                'bigcity'=> $form->get('bigcity')->getData(), 
                'category'=> $form->get('category')->getData(), 
                'events' => $events
            ]);

        }
        return $this->renderForm('front/search.html.twig', [ 
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is here

```
{% block title %}Liste des activités {{ category.title }} à {{ bigcity.name }}{% endblock %}
```

When you say {{ category.title }} or {{ bigcity.name }}, that means you call a variable category and basically (not alwyas) the variables are declared in the controller and passed to view in return render ...

In your case you call a variable category as an object, neither the variable category exists nor the object so how twig will know about them ?

the second thing, category may is exists in url as parameter but not as a full object, the id of category I guess (example &category=5&...)

So what you should do is to retrive this parameter in events function, if it exists so you must select the category having this id form the database or just select his name if you need just his name, and you pass this variable in return render and do not forget to do some test if exists to not get errors

```
#[Route('/events', name: 'events')]
public function events(Request $request, EventsRepository $eventsRepository, CategoriesRepository $categoriesRepository)
{
    $data = $request->request->all();
    $events = $eventsRepository->findAll();
    $categories = $categoriesRepository->findAll();

     $category = null;
    if($request->query->has('category'))
     {
       $categoryId = $request->query->get('category');
       // or
       // $categoryId = $data['category'];
      
      $category = $categoriesRepository->find($categoryId);
     }

    return $this->render("front/events.html.twig", [
       'data' => $data, 
       'events' => $events, 
       'categories' => $categories,
       'category' => $category // pass category to view
   ]);
}

{% if category is not null %}
    {% block title %}Liste des activités {{ category.title }} à {{ bigcity.name }}{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is pretty clear for me. I tried the solution add the parameter I need in events function. It didn't work, I probably did something wrong... but it looks like I am on the right way. I'll update my code in the description for my current EventsController.php file.

Comment: So now I ended up with this error : ```Controller "App\Controller\Front\EventsController::events()" requires that you provide a value for the "$data" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.```

Comment: Did you solve it or not yet ? If no so remove the $data from the function parameters

Comment: No, I didn't solve it yet. I just removed  the $data from events function parameters. I have this error again : ```Variable "category" does not exist.```

Comment: $categoryId = $data['category'] ; then check if isn't null if not so with doctrine you select the category from database having this id and pass it to twig in return render

Comment: Ok. I just did. I have the error again I described in this ticket.

Comment: What is the output of dd($categoryId)  ?

Comment: check the updates in my response

Comment: Ok thank you hous. At least, I managed the error. Now, I need to get the datas from the search form as it's mandatary to filter events thanks to it. I created a new ticket in order to have more discussion about it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Here is the new ticket : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73996076/in-symfony-how-do-i-pass-data-form-to-another-route-error-a-value-must-be-pro

Comment: You probably understood it, but when I tested dd($categoryId), it was empty. It's the problem I need to solve now.

Comment: I did dd($data) for $data = $request->request->all(); it's empty. I don't understand why.

Comment: I keep looking... I am sur there is a solution as it worked properly on this ticket : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73809195/how-to-retrieve-specific-values-in-my-form-symfony-6-0-2/73810167?noredirect=1#comment130379826_73810167

Comment: Basically instead of redirecting to a route, I just rendered event.html.twig. I thought I could redirect to the route I wanted, but maybe it's the solution.

Comment: I am advised against sharing my desk. Sorry and thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, hope you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

This is my current code. All I want to do is to pass values setted in `$data`coming from search form. I am sure there is a solution to do it... Thank you very much.

**EventsController.php** file

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use App\Form\SearchType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(
        Request $request, 
        SessionInterface $sessionInterface,
    ){   
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $sessionSearchFormData  = $sessionInterface->get('searchFormData');

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, ['data' => $sessionSearchFormData]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();
            $sessionInterface->set('searchFormData', $data);

            $dataRequest = [
               'bigcity'=> $form->get('bigcity')->getData() ,
               'category'=> $form->get('category')->getData() 
               ];

            $queryStringParameters = http_build_query($dataRequest);

            $url = $this->generateUrl("events").'?'.$queryStringParameters;
            return $this->redirect($url);
        }
        return $this->render('front/search.html.twig', [ 
            'form' => $form->createView() 
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/events', name: 'events')]
    public function events(
        EventsRepository $eventsRepository, 
    ){
        $events = $eventsRepository->findAll();
        return $this->render("front/events.html.twig", ['events' => $events]);
    }
}
```

**search.html.twig** file

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Liste des sorties et des activités !{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

{{ form_start(form) }}

    <p>Où souhaites-tu faire une sortie ou une activité ?</p>
    {{ form_widget(form.bigcity) }}

    <p>Quel type de sortie ou d’activité t’intéresse ?</p>
    {{ form_widget(form.category) }}

    {{ form_widget(form.save, {'label': 'Je valide') }}

{{ form_end(form) }}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248685/discussion-on-answer-by-emilie-tossan-with-symfony-how-do-i-retrieve-the-data-pr).