# In Symfony how do I pass data form to another route? Error : a value must be provided for the argument

Tags: forms, symfony, variables, controller

I built a search form where users can select a city and a category in order to discover available events.

In my controller, I made two routes: search and events. In search, I defined the search form and for events, I redirect the user toward the event.HTML.twig where he'll find the list of events according to their city and their category.

Because I am using two routes for this process, I am tempted to pass the variable `$data` which retrieves data from the search form from the first route to the second route. It looked like it didn't work at all because I ended up with this error :

```
Controller "App\Controller\Front\EventsController::events()" requires that you provide a value for the "$data" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided, or there is a nonoptional argument after this one.
```

In Symfony how do I pass `$data` values to the second route?

**EventsController.php*** file :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use App\Form\SearchType;
use App\Repository\EventsRepository;
use App\Repository\CategoriesRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class EventsController extends AbstractController
{   
    #[Route('/search', name: 'search')]
    public function search(Request $request, SessionInterface $sessionInterface)
    {   
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $sessionSearchFormData  = $sessionInterface->get('searchFormData');

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, ['data' => $sessionSearchFormData]);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $data = $form->getData();
            $sessionInterface->set('searchFormData', $data);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('events', ['data' => $data]);
        }
        return $this->renderForm('front/search.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/events', name: 'events')]
    public function events(
        $data,
        Request $request,
        EventsRepository $eventsRepository, 
        CategoriesRepository $categoriesRepository
    ){
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $events = $eventsRepository->findAll();
        $categories = $categoriesRepository->findAll();
        return $this->render("front/events.html.twig", ['data' => $data, 'events' => $events, 'categories' => $categories]);
    }
}
```

EDIT after Skuti Solution :
I tried this the first route, and I get this error :

```
Could not resolve argument $city of "App\Controller\Front\EventsController::searchform()", maybe you forgot to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the "controller.service_arguments"?
```

```
#[Route('/search/form', name: 'events_search')]
    public function searchForm(): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, null, [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('events', ['category', 'city']),
        ]);

        return $this->renderForm('front/search.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour Emilie,

Here is my suggestion:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Front;

use App\Form\SearchType;
use App\Repository\EventsRepository;
use App\Repository\CategoriesRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

#[Route('/events')]
class EventsController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/search/form', name: 'events_search_form')]
    public function searchForm(): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, null, [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('events_search', [
                'category' => null, // Or anything else if you want to directly filter
                'city' => null, // Or anything else if you want to directly filter
            ]),
        ]);

        return $this->renderForm('front/search.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/search/{city}/{category}', name: 'events_search')]
    public function search(Request $request, EventsRepository $eventsRepository, string $city, string $category): Response
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, null, [
            'method' => 'GET',
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('events_search', [
                'category' => $category,
                'city' => $city,
            ]),
        ]);
        $form->handlerRequest($request);

        $events = [];
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $events = $eventsRepository->findBy(array_merge($form->getData(), [
                'city' => $city,
                'category' => $category,
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('front/events.html.twig', [
            'data' => $data,
            'events' => $events,
            'categories' => $categories
        ]);
    }
}
```

Or a kind of. I did not test it of course and the event query must be create by yourself but you've got an idea on how to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you very much Skuti. I am testing it. I'll be back to you if I have something missing.

Comment: I have an error saying that some mandatory parameters are missing. Should I add "city" and "category" to the generateUrl('events_search') ?

Comment: My question is how can I add parameters ? I don't know how I can get and add $data without saying when $form is submitted and valid...

Comment: I shared at the end of description what I did.

Comment: You should keep the route as I wrote in my example. The only thing you have to do is to define parameters city and category as optional (https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#optional-parameters). This will work normally after optional parameter. And if you want to filter events by city or category then you could pass city or category parameters in your URL. Or you could remove category and city parameters and defined them in your form. As you want.

Comment: Thank you Skuti, but it's said that as soon as we add a parameter to a route, it must have a value. I don't want city and category to be optional : they are mandatory for researches done with my search form.

Comment: I just don't know how to set them as parameters in the URL.

Comment: In TWIG: `{{ path('events_search', {category: 'a category', city: 'a city'}) }}`

Comment: In Controller: `$this->generateUrl('events_search', ['category' => 'a category', 'city' => 'a city'])`

Comment: Ok thank you Skuti. I updated my controller but I don't know how to add ```{{ path('events_search', {category: 'a category', city: 'a city'}) }}``` in twig because I use ```{{ form(form) }}```.

Comment: My question is how do I use ```path('events_search', {category: 'a category', city: 'a city'}) }}```?

Comment: You don't have to use path() in Twig when you use form. You have to set action of your form as shown on my example.

Comment: I have to say neither 'category' and nor 'city' must be null as my search form has mandatory selections. It's impossible for me to display the event.html.twig without 'category' and 'city'.

Comment: I tried something. I updated the EDIT part in my description but it didn't work.

Comment: Do your category and city are a part of your search form? If yes, you should remove the category and the city from the route definition and adjust your code in consequence. I just put those route parameters because I thought you wanted them like this base on your first post. The only thing you should keep is the method of your form as GET.